# What's the correct DropDownListFor HTML helper syntax for this static list with a selected value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Could someone help me with the proper syntax?

Not sure how to write the DropDownListFor HTML helper. How would I write this with "Mouse" selected based on the Value property of 3? I'm not using a model, just trying to whip up a quick list within razor.

Thanks

```
var AnimalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dog", Value = "1" });
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cat", Value = "2" });
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mouse", Value = "3" });
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Squirrel", Value = "4" });
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Fox", Value = "5" });


@Html.DropDownListFor(? , ?, ?);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `@Html.DropDownListFor` without model. But you can use `@Html.DropDownList` without model.

**In controller**

```
var AnimalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dog", Value = "1" });
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cat", Value = "2" });
AnimalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mouse", Value = "3" });
this.ViewBag.Animals = new SelectList(AnimalList, "Value", "Text", "3");
```

**In view**

```
@Html.DropDownList("myDropDown", ViewBag.Animals as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `DropDownListFor` without a model.  Look at its overloads: everyone starts with a model property.  That's what the helper uses to set the name attribute for the model binder.

You can, however use `DropDownList`.  Notice that the first argument in each of it's overloads is `string name`.  Here you set the name attribute yourself.

```
@Html.DropDownList("myDropDownList", AnimalList)
```

You don't set an item to selected in the helper, you do that in the SelectListItem declaration like this

```
AnimalList.Add( new SelectListItem 
                    { 
                      Text = "Mouse", 
                      Value = "3", 
                      Selected = true 
                    } 
              );
```